# ave and which.max in R

Tags: r

I have a question about getting index values using which.max() in the ave function.  I start with the following data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(t_subjNum = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                 t_trialNum= c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
                 perpdist =  c(50,51,49,2,3,4,2,1,2,2,1,4,5,2,2),
                 angdiff =   c(60,61,60,-80,-81,-82,-81,40,41,42,41,61,60,61,62))
```

I would like to pull the `angdiff` for the maximum absolute `perpdist` of each `t_subjNum` by `t_trialNum` interaction.  So, I made a formula like this:

```
df$maxangleINCORRECT   <- ave(df$perpdist, 
                       interaction(df$t_subjNum, df$t_trialNum), 
                       FUN = function(x) df$angdiff[which.max(abs(x))])
```

It results in the wrong `angdiff` values. It creates an index for the subset of observations in the `t_subjNum` and `t_trialNum` interaction (e.g., 3 rather than 6 for `subjNum` = 1 and `trialNum` = 2).  Any ideas on how to fix the indexing here?

Just to illustrate the incorrect result and the desired correct result.

```
   t_subjNum t_trialNum perpdist angdiff maxangleINCORRECT maxangleCORRECT
1          1          1       50      60                61              61
2          1          1       51      61                61              61
3          1          1       49      60                61              61
4          1          2        2     -80                60             -82
5          1          2        3     -81                60             -82
6          1          2        4     -82                60             -82
7          1          2        2     -81                60             -82
8          2          1        1      40                61              41
9          2          1        2      41                61              41
10         2          1        2      42                61              41
11         2          1        1      41                61              41
12         2          2        4      61                61              60
13         2          2        5      60                61              60
14         2          2        2      61                61              60
15         2          2        2      62                61              60
```

Comment: Yes, I made a typo.  Sorry.  Should be fixed now.

Comment: ave equivalent `with(df, ave(seq.int(nrow(df)), interaction(t_subjNum, t_trialNum), FUN = function(x) angdiff[x][which.max(abs(perpdist[x]))]))`

Comment: @rawr The op's comment below suggests he is also interested in a base option. You could post as an answer. That also works fine if you don't wrap in `interaction()`, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried tinkering with `ave`, but found it quite complicated as it takes one numeric as argument, so as you already found `which.max` gives you trouble. You could consider using `data.table`. I realize the output of this doesn't match maxAngleCORRECT, but I think that's something to do with ties (with t_subjNum==2 and t_trialNum==2, max abs(perpdist) is 5, leadong to an anglediff of 60.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,maxangle:=angdiff[which.max(abs(perpdist))],by=.(t_subjNum,t_trialNum)]
```

Comment: This is correct.  I made a typo in the original post.  Should be fixed now.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the data.table library?